# How can I predict if the binding site of a DNA-binding protein is located on the promoter sequence of a gene?

Tags: bioconductor, genome, proteins, computation, transposable-elements

Is there any computational tool or any other method to predict if the binding site of DNA binding protein is actually located on a promoter sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I computationally predict the binding position of a DNA binding protein on the promoters of differentially expressed genes?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/8691/how-do-i-computationally-predict-the-binding-position-of-a-dna-binding-protein-o)

Answer (score 1):

You could run [FIMO](http://meme-suite.org/doc/fimo.html) on your entire genome for TFs (transcription factors; DNA-binding proteins) of interest, which gives you predicted binding sites: genomic intervals where those TFs bind, with some statistical significance.

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2491/776

You can then map or intersect promoter regions with those TF binding sites with BEDOPS `bedmap` or `bedops`, respectively:

https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/statistics/bedmap.html

https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/set-operations/bedops.html

You can define your promoter regions however you like, e.g., from the TSS to 2.5kb upstream of the TSS. It's up to you and your experiment.

The use of `bedmap` is recommended to assign TFs to a promoter of interest. This tool will return both the promoter region and any TFs that overlap it by the specified overlap criteria.